# Does Oracle JDk support Intel Architecture, 32-bit (IA® -32)?

Tags: java, linux

Currently, we are using IBM JDK(JRE) 1.6.0_04 because it supports this hardware platform Intel Architecture, 32-bit (IA®-32) I want to update the JDK in the project but I'm not sure Oracle JDK support this platform?

Comment: What is your specific reason for running on hardware that's over 10 years old?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Their reasons are not really our business. Besides, if good computer hardware is still running well, why throw it out?

Answer (score 1):

I see only 64-bit offerings on the Oracle JDK site for [Java downloads](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-linux). But if you are an Oracle customer, you should call your sales representative or technical support for more information.

As for your mention of IBM, [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/java-sdk-downloads) shows 32-bit builds of Java 8. But their Java 11 builds are listed only for 64-bit systems. But, again, if you are a customer of IBM, contact your sales or support rep.

Other vendors offer 32-bit builds. For example, Azul Systems [offers JDK builds for Java 17 on
x86 32-bit](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-17-lts&architecture=x86-32-bit&package=jdk) for both Linux and MS Windows, and 32-bit builds for Java 8 & 11 too.

You could check with other vendors as well, such as SAP, Red Hat, Microsoft, Amazon, BellSoft, Pivotal, etc.